# Keystore generation with KeyTool command

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

While generating keystore by using keytool I receive error illegal option: genkeypair.
But when I see help genkeypair is available as option. What am I doing wrong in command?

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>keytool.exe -genkeypair -alias
>   orbis -storetype pkcs12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore
>   d:\Certificates\orbisKeyStore.p12

Comment: Try with the interactive way: `keytool.exe -genkeypair`

Comment: Tried with keytool.exe but no luck

Comment: I had the same error. In my case, I had an erroneous space between a dash '-' and the following switch.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to just use your IDE to do your job.

> **Right click on project --> Android Tools --> Export Signed Application Package --> Create New Key Store**

and then just follow the wizard. You can also follow this [link](http://www.programmingodyssey.com/2013/01/create-signed-android-application-using.html)

Comment: I am doing it for a web sphere application and i am generating it on client machine where development environment is not available.

Comment: @Tanveer I am very sorry, i just checked, came to know that you are not working on Android.

Comment: Thanks for your effort